# How the added class can use the attributes of the main class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

So, I have this class ComplexSystem. This class has its own attributes (attr_a in this example). It also has several elements. During another procedure, a method of the elements is called and attributes of the ComplexSystem are required for calculation of something. How should I do it? I have provided an example down here:

```
class ComplexSystem:

    def  __init__(self, attr_a):
        self.attr_a  = attr_a
        self.elements = []

    def add_element(self, element):
        self.elements.append(element)

class Element:

    def do_something(self):
    ### I want to use the attr_a of the ComplexSystem here, what should I do?


mySystem = ComplexSystem("foo")
new_element = Element()
mySystem.add_element(new_element)
mySystem.elements[0].do_something()
```

Answer (score 2):

you can't access that attribute because your `Element` object has no idea about the `ComplexSystem` class. There are some ways to gain access to that attribute.

1- you can define `attr_a` as a static property (it's not always possible)

2- you can pass your `ComplexSystem` object to your `Element` objects (check @milanbalazs answer)

3- add a property to your `Element` class and assign its value when adding to `ComplexSystem`

```
class ComplexSystem:

    def  __init__(self, attr_a):
        self.attr_a  = attr_a
        self.elements = []

    def add_element(self, element):
        element.assign_attr(self.attr_a)
        self.elements.append(element)

class Element:

    def assign_attr(self, value):
       self.complex_system_attr = value
```

4- add another class to handle the data. you can pass `attr_a` to `do_somthing` method of your `Element` class, and you should store `ElementList` object in your `ComplexSystem` class, instead of the current list. example:

```
class ElementList:
  
   def __init__(self, elements, attr_a):
       self.attr_a = attr_a
       self.elements = elements

   def do_something(self, index):
       self.elements[index].do_something(self.attr_a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more possible solution. You didn't share enough info for selecting the optimal for you.

You can pass the instance of `ComplexSystem` to `Element` class (I guess it is OK in your case).

```
class Element:

    def __init__(self, complex_system_inst):
        self.complex_system_inst = complex_system_inst

    def do_something(self):
        print("attr_a from Element: {}".format(self.complex_system_inst.attr_a))


mySystem = ComplexSystem("foo")
new_element = Element(mySystem)
mySystem.add_element(new_element)
mySystem.elements[0].do_something()
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
attr_a from Element: foo
```

---

---

In your case you can use your `mySystem` object because it is in scope (Like a global variable).

```
class Element:

    @staticmethod
    def do_something():
        print("attr_a from Element: {}".format(mySystem.attr_a))


mySystem = ComplexSystem("foo")
new_element = Element()
mySystem.add_element(new_element)
mySystem.elements[0].do_something()
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
python3 test.py
attr_a from Element: foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
class ComplexSystem:

    def  __init__(self, attr_a):
        self.attr_a  = attr_a
        self.elements = []

    def add_element(self, element):
        e = Element()
        e.assign_attr(self.attr_a)
        self.elements.append(e)

class Element:
    def assign_attr(self, value):
       self.complex_system_attr = value
```